# Win32 batch scripts always fail pgAgent

Tags: postgresql, job-scheduling, pgadmin, pgadmin-4, pgagent

PostgreSQL batch script always fail not running.

below job script query....

> DO $$ DECLARE
>       jid integer;
>       scid integer; BEGIN
>   -- Creating a new job INSERT INTO pgagent.pga_job(
>       jobjclid, jobname, jobdesc, jobhostagent, jobenabled ) VALUES (
>       1::integer, 'Execute_batch002'::text, ''::text, ''::text, true ) RETURNING jobid INTO jid;
>
> -- Steps
>   -- Inserting a step (jobid: NULL) INSERT INTO pgagent.pga_jobstep (
>       jstjobid, jstname, jstenabled, jstkind,
>       jstconnstr, jstdbname, jstonerror,
>       jstcode, jstdesc ) VALUES (
>       jid, 'Action1'::text, true, 'b'::character(1),
>       ''::text, ''::name, 'f'::character(1),
>       'C:\Script\Test_backup.bat'::text, ''::text ) ;
>
> -- Schedules
>   -- Inserting a schedule INSERT INTO pgagent.pga_schedule(
>       jscjobid, jscname, jscdesc, jscenabled,
>       jscstart, jscend,    jscminutes, jschours, jscweekdays, jscmonthdays, jscmonths ) VALUES (
>       jid, 'Sch_1'::text, ''::text, true,
>       '2018-03-28 00:00:01+05:30'::timestamp with time zone, '2055-07-16 00:00:01+05:30'::timestamp with time zone,
>       -- Minutes
>       ARRAY[false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
>   false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
>   false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
>   false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
>   false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
>   false, false]::boolean[],
>       -- Hours
>       ARRAY[true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true,
>   true, true, true]::boolean[],
>       -- Week days
>       ARRAY[true, true, true, true, true, true, true]::boolean[],
>       -- Month days
>       ARRAY[true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true,
>   true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true,
>   false]::boolean[],
>       -- Months
>       ARRAY[true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]::boolean[] ) RETURNING jscid INTO scid; END $$;

check below statistics of above job. 
Always running and aborted status.
[link_1](https://ibb.co/hcqfH7)

Comment: Do you see any errors in the log file?

Comment: where i can find log. without PgAgent job batch file running perfectly.

Comment: A few questions: Could you share with us what this batch file is doing? Can you make this batch file to write a log? Is there anything at the postgresql log files? I manage a database with pgagent running several batch files for some years now, and I never had this problem (I use linux though).

Comment: batch file just take backup postgres database, without pgagent batch script running fine, but after schedule it with PgAgent always shown running status or after some time shown aborted.